# Passing a field to a function to sort on that field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, lambda, func

I am writing a function with a signature like this where I am sorting the model data among other things:

```
public MyModel GetModel(IQueryable<Something> query, string sort, 
   int page, int PageSize)
{
   ...
   viewModel.Something = query.OrderByDescending(o => sort)
          .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
   ...
}
```

Problem is I want to pass in a default sort parameter which is what I want to sort against if the parameter "sort" is null or empty. For example, this might be:

```
.OrderByDescending(o => o.AddedDate);
```

I have tried all sorts of things (for instance passing in a Func) to pass in something to this function to tell it to use `AddedDate` or whatever I choose to sort the records if sort is null but nothing works. How would I implement such a thing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic LINQ OrderBy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code doesn't make much sense - you are sorting by a single value, not a property of the items you want to sort - if you want to be able to sort by any string property within your `Something` class more appropriate would be:

```
public MyModel GetModel(IQueryable<Something> query, Func<Something, string> sort, 
   int page, int PageSize)
{
   Func<Something, string> actualSort = sort ?? (o => o.AddedDate);
   ...
   viewModel.Something = query.OrderByDescending(actualSort)
          .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
   ...
}
```

Now if you pass in `null` for `sort` the sorting will revert to the default sort order by `AddedDate`.

Comment: I think the OP wants to be able to choose the sort key dynamically at runtime, so a Func won't work in this case...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: That's not how I read the question, but of course I might be wrong- leaving this up until OP can clarify.

Comment: @Thomas - that is exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx). It allows you to pass the sort key as a string:

```
query.OrderByDescending(sort)...
```

Comment: Copy the DynamicQuery.cs file from Visual Studio samples into your project, add a `using System.Linq.Dynamic;` in your code, and you're good to go ; you will see the new OrderBy overloads in intellisense

Comment: I searched, I don't have DynamicQuery on my computer and even if I did, not sure how it would help.

Comment: @Sachin, did you read the link I posted? It explains where you can download the samples, and where you can find the file in the samples.